# Collision response and elastic impulse in XNA 4.0

Tags: c#, xna, physics, collision

I know there are physic plugins for C# or XNA, but I want to create my own, so I can learn about the topic.

My problems are the following:

I try to apply an elastic impulse to my character with the right angle and velocity. The velocity is calculated the right way, the angle is not and distorts the results!
The next problem is, that my character gets into a shaking mode, though it should stand still. I know where the problem comes from, but I don't know how to fix it (edit: do I have to consider the penetration depth for that?)

The `IPhysicsObject` inherits the most important informations, the `Vector2[]` has the collisionPoint at index 0 and the penetration depth at index 1.

I have tried to work with [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elastic_collision) but yeah.. I don't know

```
    public void ElasticImpulse(IPhysicsObject Object, Vector2[] _colPos)
    {
        //this function is down below
        if (checkCollidingObjects(m_cCharacter, Object))
            return;

        //this List is like this declined:
        //public static List<IPhysicsObject[]> CollidingObjects = new List<IPhysicsObject[]>();
        //this list contains every pair of objects, that collided this frame, it is cleared after all physics and game logic is done.
        CollidingObjects.Add(new IPhysicsObject[] { m_cCharacter, Object });

        //deltavelocity is the velocity between two frames
        Vector2 v1 = Velocity - DeltaVelocity;
        float lv1 = (float)Math.Sqrt(v1.X * v1.X + v1.Y * v1.Y);
        float m1 = Mass;
        float k1 = Damping;

        Vector2 v2 = Object.Physik.Velocity - Object.Physik.DeltaVelocity;
        float lv2 = (float)Math.Sqrt(v2.X * v2.X + v2.Y * v2.Y);
        float m2 = Object.Mass;
        float k2 = Object.Physik.Damping;

        Vector2 colDir1 = _colPos[0] - m_cCharacter.Position;
        Vector2 colDir2 = _colPos[0] - Object.Position;
        colDir1.Normalize();
        colDir2.Normalize();
        Vector2 colNorm1 = new Vector2(colDir1.Y, -colDir1.X);
        Vector2 colNorm2 = new Vector2(colDir2.Y, -colDir2.X);
        float ldir1 = (float)Math.Sqrt(colNorm1.X * colNorm1.X + colNorm1.Y * colNorm1.Y);
        float ldir2 = (float)Math.Sqrt(colNorm2.X * colNorm2.X + colNorm2.Y * colNorm2.Y);

        float pi = MathHelper.Pi;
        //float angle1 = pi - ((v1.X * colNorm1.X + v2.Y * colNorm1.Y) / (lv1 * ldir1)) / v1.Length();
        float angle1 = pi - (float)Math.Acos(((v1.X * colNorm1.X + v2.Y * colNorm1.Y) / (lv1 * ldir1)) / v1.Length());
        angle1 = (float.IsNaN(angle1)) ? 0 : angle1;
        //float angle2 = pi - ((v2.X * colNorm2.X + v2.Y * colNorm2.Y) / (lv2 * ldir1)) / v2.Length();
        float angle2 = pi - (float)Math.Acos(((v2.X * colNorm2.X + v2.Y * colNorm2.Y) / (lv2 * ldir1)) / v2.Length());
        angle2 = (float.IsNaN(angle2)) ? 0 : angle2;

        //calculating the new velocities u 1/2. Got this formula out of the wiki link i posted above (took the german wiki version)
        Vector2 u1 = (m1 * v1 + m2 * v2 - (m2 * (v1 - v2) * k2)) / (m1 + m2) - v1;
        Vector2 u2 = (m1 * v1 + m2 * v2 - (m1 * (v2 - v1) * k1)) / (m1 + m2) - v2;

        //transform the new velocities by the correct angle
        Vector2 newV1 = new Vector2(
            u1.X * (float)Math.Cos(angle1) - u1.Y * (float)Math.Sin(angle1),
            u1.X * (float)Math.Sin(angle1) + u1.Y * (float)Math.Cos(angle1));
        Vector2 newV2 = new Vector2(
            u2.X * (float)Math.Cos(angle2) - u2.Y * (float)Math.Sin(angle2),
            u2.X * (float)Math.Sin(angle2) + u2.Y * (float)Math.Cos(angle2));

        newV1 = new Vector2(
            (float.IsNaN(newV1.X)) ? 0 : newV1.X,
            (float.IsNaN(newV1.Y)) ? 0 : newV1.Y);
        newV2 = new Vector2(
            (float.IsNaN(newV2.X)) ? 0 : newV2.X,
            (float.IsNaN(newV2.Y)) ? 0 : newV2.Y);
        AddForce(newV1);
        Object.Physik.AddForce(newV2);
    }

    bool checkCollidingObjects(IPhysicsObject obj1, IPhysicsObject obj2)
    {
        if (CollidingObjects.Count > 0)
        {
            int a = CollidingObjects.FindIndex(x => (x[0] == obj1 && x[1] == obj2) || 
                                                    (x[1] == obj1 && x[0] == obj2));
            return a != -1;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: The shaking I think you are talking about is when an object is fighting itself for its direction - such as when your object is being pulled by gravity downwards, but your collision handling is making it move back upwards

Comment: yeah i know that. Normally i just canceled to add the gravity constant to stop it. But i wanted to do it a bit more realistic now. I add an anti gravity force now how should negate the gravity so the character stand still. I think the problem lays in the impulse function too. My prediction is it doesn't stop to bounce.

i wanted to add a simple version of the real physics. you can say a miniminiminiminiminimized version. ;)

Comment: Generally, you should not mess with angles if you can avoid it. And in this case you can. Could you add a figure of the collision? It is not clear what the variables stand for (e.g. `DeltaVelocity`, `colNorm1/2`, `u` ...). How can you calculate the collision normal from the velocities? That depends on the body's shape. Or do you have standard objects (e.g. spheres)? Is one of the bodies fixed or are they both moveable? The shaking is probably caused by multiple collisions where there should be only one (and therefore multiple reflections of the velocity vector).

Comment: ok, sorry that i forgot to mention it! This is only a 2D Game and i'm just messing around with Rectangles. In my tests now i got only one moveable (my character) and the ground he should bounce of but i want to keep it as universal as possible (for enemy or item bouncing, idk). i managed to fix the angle Problem by taking 
´float angle1 = pi - (float)....´ this and transformed it into ´float angle = Vector2.Dot(v1, colNorm1) / lv1;´ this
I already did this in previous versions but always forgot to divide by the length (the velocity is no unit vector, i forgot that i need one... stupid me)

Comment: i added a piece of information, do you need more, or is this enough?